# What are my options for running a depricated library with dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, docker, container

So my introduction to robotics class is using ROS indigo(apparently a lot of the existing codebase isn't easily ported to newer versions) which is running on a depricated version of ubuntu (teacher says 10, slides for a couple of weeks for now say 14). I would rather avoid installing a non-supported version of ubuntu on my pc, and from what he said when they tried to run it in a VM before it was terribly slow (though I could pursue that route depending on the performance of KVM or xen based virtualization).

I want to know what options I have if I neither want to install a deprecated operating system with class-specific codebase or try to run the operating system in a VM. I'm not familiar with the options available. Bonus points if the option doesn't take extensive background knowledge to set up.

Comment: How many weeks is your class? Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS doesn't go EOL until April 2019 AFAIK - see [wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: 16 weeks, didn't know it was still supported